# How to load URL with headers in WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to load a URL in a WebView and add headers `User-Agent` and `autoToken`.
I have tried to just have `val map = HashMap<String, String>()` and add it as `webview.loadUrl(url, map)`.

The second try was to just override `shouldInterceptRequest()`.

```
override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest): WebResourceResponse? {
    request.requestHeaders?.put(LegacyAuthInterceptor.HEADER_AUTH_TICKET, autoToken)
   request.requestHeaders?.put("User-Agent", userAgent)
    return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
  }
```

None of these solutions are working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val map = HashMap<String, String>()
map[AUTO_TOKEN] = autoToken
webClientBinding.webView.settings.userAgentString = userAgent
WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)
webClientBinding.webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
  override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest): WebResourceResponse? {
    CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null)
    return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request)
  }
}
webClientBinding.webView.loadUrl(url, map)
```

It should work!

Answer (score 5):

Use following for changing `User-Agent`

`webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("userAgent");`

Ideally `webview.loadUrl(url, map)` should suffice to add the headers. Following in another alternative by overriding methods in `WebViewClient`:

```
@Override
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request){
    view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString(),headerMap);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
    view.loadUrl(url,headerMap);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. In my case, the page requires access token, I needed to put authorization token on every request from either `loadUrl(String, Map)` of Android's WebView and ```submit``` of Form in HTML.