# Android WebView - How can I see Headers?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, webview

I can see a cookie with the code below

```
 String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
```

but I couldn't figure out how to get headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer
if you want to get response header,
[Access the http response headers in a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134389/access-the-http-response-headers-in-a-webview)

or if you want to attach request header, just use attach map when call webView.loadUrl()
[How to load URL with headers in WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50878560/how-to-load-url-with-headers-in-webview)