# Transferring an access token from native mobile app to browser

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

We have some features that are only supported in the web experience and not mobile. Is there a way where an access token for a user in say myTestApp (an android application) can be transferred safely to a cookie in myTestApp.com, when the user clicks a button on the app?

In other words, when going from a mobile app, to chrome, how can we avoid asking the user to log in again?

Comment: You could add it as query in the URL but it wouldn't be wise. Maybe add it as request Header in built-in WebView: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50878560/how-to-load-url-with-headers-in-webview

Comment: My previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832802/how-to-share-authentication-between-mobile-app-and-webview/74842376#74842376) discusses this.